# Constexpr version of function gives different result when called the same way

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

static constexpr bool f1()
{
    auto p = new int(1);

    delete p;    

    auto q = new int(2);
    
    delete q;
            
    return p == q;
}

static bool f2() // Same body as f1
{
    auto p = new int(1);

    delete p;    

    auto q = new int(2);
    
    delete q;
            
    return p == q;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr bool i1 = f1();
    
    std::cout << i1 << std::endl;
    
    auto i2 = f2();
    
    std::cout << i2 << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation command line:

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -pedantic-errors main.cpp -o prog
```

Output from running `prog` (this is what I got, but may be different for you):

```
0
1
```

How is this possible? How is it even possible that I am allowed to define `f1` that way given that it has unspecified behaviour?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing values of invalidated pointers. Any outcome of such a program is correct.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I am using clang++ with the following command line: clang++ -std=c++20 -pedantic-errors main.cpp -o prog

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: This is the version that I am using: clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1  Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /usr/bin

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, By my reading, reading invalid pointers is [implementation-defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4).

Comment: @Supermom Are you sure you want to be comparing pointer values and not the values pointed to? Comparing pointer values is undefined if they are not from the same allocation.

Comment: Re: why the program compiles. "**[dcl.constexpr]/6** For a constexpr function ..., if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function ... could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (7.7),... the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required."

Comment: They aren't dereferencing those pointers. Afaik, this program will just print different values every time since `new` isn't guaranteed to allocate at the same address consecutively.

Comment: @Supremum From [Pointer comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Pointer_comparison_operators) yours would fall into this case: "*If two pointers are not specified to compare greater or compare equal, the result of the comparison is unspecified. The result may be nondeterministic, and need not be consistent even for multiple evaluations of the same expression with the same operands in the same execution of the program*".

Comment: @dxiv: Yeah, but shouldn't constexpr functions be determinisitic?

Comment: _How is it even possible that I am allowed to define f1 that way given that it has unspecified behaviour?_  C++ is not a nanny language.  It presumes you know what you are doing, and if you are doing unspecified (potentially non-deterministic) behavior that it is intentional.  Enabling all your compiler warnings can help, but they won't do holistic analysis (because of the possibly very lengthy increase of compilation time).  Other static analysis tools, like Coverity, can do much more expensive analysis, and do that across translation units.

Comment: @Supremum Besides the comments right above, the posted code does not even compare two calls to the same constexpr function.

Comment: @Supremum The new question after the edit is no longer quite the same, and it is not entirely clear what you mean by "*unspecified*" and "*non-deterministic*" in this context. Would `constexpr bool f()` `{ return ((uintptr_t)(void*)f & 0x10000) != 0; }` qualify? It does "*output 0 or 1*" between different runs on my machine (with ASLR enabled).

Comment: @Supremum I have rolled this question back to match the answer that was already provided.  If you have a follow-up question, please ask a new question.  That will prevent the work that was done in answering your first question from becoming invalidated.

Comment: @dxiv _If two pointers are not specified to compare greater or compare equal, the result of the comparison is unspecified_ The quote from cppreference speaks about [\[expr.rel\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.rel#4), the result of `>=`, `<=`, `>`, `<` comparisons. For equality comparison, [the result is unspecified iff one pointer value represents the address of a complete object and the other represents the address past the end another complete object](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.eq#2.1), so the the quote from cppreference doesn't apply here.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik _Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing values of invalidated pointers_ It is not UB unless the implementation defined it as UB.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The paragraph on cppreference refers to *all* of what they call "*comparison operators*" *including* `==`. Whether and how that maps to the wording in the standard is a different matter. That's one reason why I left mine as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @chris _By my reading, reading invalid pointers is implementation-defined_ You're right, but your link is wrong. [basic.stc]/4 tells that the **use** of invalid pointer value is implementation-defined, not **reading**. You can't use value before you have it. And to have it, you need to read it. And the effect of reading is indeed implementation-defined, but this is specified in [conv.lval].

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Also IMO the potential UB due to usage of freed/invalid pointers is mostly a technicality which obfuscates the real question more than it helps it. The potential UB could be easily avoided by saving the pointers to intermediate variables `uintptr_t a = (uintptr_t)p;` while they *are* valid then `return a == b;`.

Comment: @dxiv _Whether and how that maps to the wording in the standard is a different matter_ In my comment, I wasn't explaining how cppreference is mapped to the Standard wording, I was explaining why there is no unspecified comparison here.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer, Good point, thank you. I skipped a step when I was reading that.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a pointer invalidates it.

Any use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior (except for indirecting through and passing to a deallocation function, which have undefined behaviour; neither is done in the example).

In the example that behaviour happened to be different in two slightly different cases.

---

> How is this possible?

The compiler produced a program that outputs "0\n1". It is possible.

If you want to know if this conforms to the standard: Yes.

---

Whether this is intentional by the implementation... I suspect not directly, but rather by coincidence. My entirely hypothetical guess about the implementation:

There may be a piece of logic that sets invalid pointers to null. This has the useful side-effect that programs that have "use after free" bug (undefined behaviour) are less likely to read/write arbitrary memory (heap smashing) and instead avoid that due to null pointer check, or outright crash due to indirecting through null pointer. This potentially would reduce the severity of security vulnerabilities caused by such bug. As a side-effect, two unspecified values that would happen to be null pointers would also happen to compare equal.

But in constexpr case there may be another piece of logic which analyses that the pointers never point to same object and therefore are never equal, and constant-fold the return value as false before the null "protection" occurs.

---

Standard quote:

> [basic.stc]
>
> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become invalid pointer values. Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior. Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.<sup>31</sup>
>
> 31. Some implementations might define that copying an invalid pointer value causes a system-generated runtime fault.
>     ⮥

Comment: Nevermind, comments removed. The OP changed the question so that point is moot now.

Comment: @dxiv I have restored the question that was answered here.